# powerpivot 2010 pivot table new measure for percentage difference

Tags: percentage, powerpivot, variance

I'm a newbie with PowerPivot 2010.  I've created a few reports, but I'm having difficulty with a report that I want to create that requires a new measure.  In my volume table I have 2 columns in my volume table (`tblPilot_Volume`) - `Current Wk Vol This` and `Current Wk Vol Last`.  I want to display in the pivot the percentage difference between these two values.

I tried the calculation below but it doesn't work.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
=sum(tblPilot_Volume[Current Wk Vol This]-(tblPilot_Volume[Current Wk Vol Last])/(tblPilot_Volume[Current Wk Vol Last])
```

Prior to this I tried to just add a column to the PowerPivot table with the formula.  The calculations works in the table, but when I create the pivot table it doesn't work.

I also need to eliminate any rows where there is a zero in the `Current wk Vol Last` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ME Miller, I would try this:

```
=(sum(tblPilot_Volume[Current Wk Vol This])-sum(tblPilot_Volume[Current Wk Vol Last])) / sum(tblPilot_Volume[Current Wk Vol Last])
```

When creating measures, make sure you always use one of the aggregation functions (like sum, avg, min, max etc.).

Hope this helps.

Comment: similarly, if you drop your variables into the values part of the table first, Powerpivot will automatically create new "Sum of" measures which can be accessed in DAX, e.g. the above would become: `=(tblPilot_Volume[Sum of Current Wk Vol This]-tblPilot_Volume[Sum of Current Wk Vol Last]) / tblPilot_Volume[Sum of Current Wk Vol Last])`

Comment: random algebra note, not sure if it makes the calculation more efficient, but (A-B)/B = A/B-1. It's certainly more readable with one less reference to a column name.